# Formatting rows in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, formatting

I have a few datagridview's, listing different bits and bobs from a mysql database.

One of them has a column called 'outcome'.

This can be either 'Yes', 'Pending' or 'No'.

I need to format this list based on that value.

I'm using the following at the moment...

```
 Private Sub nb_myleads_dgv_CellFormattin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles nb_myleads_dgv.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = nb_myleads_dgv.Columns("outcome").Index Then
        If e.Value.ToString = "Yes" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
        ElseIf e.Value.ToString = "Pending" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
        ElseIf e.Value.ToString = "No" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
        End If
 End sub


    End If
```

It seem that I have to have my column 'outcome' visible in the DGV for this to work.
I have gotten around this by setting this column width to 3 pixels, but that seems a little dirty. Is it not possible to format cells in a datagridview based on the value of a hidden column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions: Do you even get past if statement? If column is hidden do you get proper value for e.RowIndex?

Comment: `CellFormattin[g]` is an expensive place to do that because it is called very often. Try `the RowsAdded` event

Answer (score 1):

Why not just loop through the rows with a for each and colorize based on the cell value. It won't matter if it's visible or not.

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            Select Case row.Cells(2).Value.ToString
                Case "Yes"
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
                Case "Pending"
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
                Case "No"
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed

            End Select
        End If
    Next
```

Where in this case, column 3 (cells(2) is hidden. You would do this after populating the grid instead of in the cellformatting

Comment: Ditto - unless you have thousands of rows refreshing the background yourself is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that cell has to be visible, otherwise it will never pass if statement.

> The CellFormatting event occurs every time each **cell is painted**, so
>   you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event. This
>   event also occurs when the cell FormattedValue is retrieved or its
>   GetFormattedValue method is called.

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would get rid off this if statement and do something like this:

```
        Dim str as string = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["outcome"].Value.ToString
        If str = "Yes" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
        ElseIf str = "Pending" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
        ElseIf str = "No" Then
            nb_myleads_dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
        End If
```